# ServiceStack EndpointHostConfig & WebHost does not exist? C# MVC

Tags: c#, servicestack, visual-studio-2013

Following a tutorial of using ServiceStack, I'm trying to compile the following code:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost() : base("Protein Tracker Web Services", typeof(HelloService).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig { ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "api" });
    }
}
```

This gives me the following error:

> The type or namespace name '**EndpointHostConfig**' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried to add the suggested:

```
using ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints;
```

Gives me the following error:

> The type or namespace name '**WebHost**' does not exist in the namespace 'ServiceStack' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: right click on references, click add references, click Browse, locate assembly containing ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.

Comment: are you using an IDE, or compiling from command line, you don't say.

Comment: if using visual studio, http://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack/

Comment: @BlackICE
Trying to locate ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints is impossible. It simply does not exist anywhere..

I tried both downloading ServiceStack from nuget gui and from console using:

PM> Install-Package ServiceStack

Installation completes but there is no ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.

Rightclicking EndpointHostConfig does not have any "resolve"-function.

Any help appreciated,

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2013, MVC 4

Comment: Your example is probably ServiceStack version 3. ServiceStack v4 the commercial release has just come out (in beta). As such you may have references to the wrong version. A lot of stuff has been refactored.

Comment: @Scott 
You are correct, the tutorial is of servicestack V3 and running command:
Install-Package ServiceStack -Version 3.9.71 
solved my problem with references

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You are probably referencing the v4 ServiceStack framework which has just been released into beta.** There has been a lot of refactoring and restructuring of the namespaces and classes which is where the conflict will arise.

[These release notes for v4](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes#the-big-refactor-of-v4) discuss the significant changes made to ServiceStack from v3 to v4.

The part most relevant to you is:

> EndpointHostConfig is now HostConfig and is limited to just Configuration.

---

A lot of the tutorials are still for v3 which is OpenSource, which is what I suspect you are following.

You should include the version number in your nu-get install. Such as:

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack -Version 3.9.71
```

This will get you the latest OpenSource version of ServiceStack (3.9.71). Or alternatively see the v4 documentation.

[v3 Documentation - Relevant for your tutorials](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3/wiki)
[v4 (Latest - commercial)](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much~
You have no idea how thankful I am to this response. I wish I could thank you somehow @_@

Comment: @myslex You're very welcome. Good luck with ServiceStack, it's a great platform.

Answer (score 3):

For those may be following outdated tutorials/examples, but wish to use the new v4 API:

> The `ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory` used
>   in Web.config's handler mapping has been renamed to just
>   `ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory`

This requires a quick update to our service's Web.config:

```
<handlers>
  <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error, it is because of the version in service stack.
Just change:
**EndpointHostConfig**  to  **HostConfig**
**ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath** to **HandlerFactoryPath**

Hope it helps.